# AngularJS - Http basic authentication via $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, authentication

i'm trying to do a login service to my app but something went wrong.
Here is my $http:

```
$http({
        method:"get",
        url: ## BLAH BLAH BLAH,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + $base64.encode(loginData.usuario + ':' + loginData.senha)
        }
    }).then(function success(response){
        ## BLAH BLAH BLAH
    }, function error(response){
        ## BLAH BLAH BLAH
    });
```

When i run that $http it show a error on console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ## BLAH BLAH BLAH. 
Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

What i'm doing wrong? 
Sincerely,
Lucas.

Comment: Your server hasn't added `Authorization` as a valid header in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` property in its CORS configuration

Comment: Ok. It's right, ;)

Answer (score 0):

checkout the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), notice that www.balabala/api is not same with balabala/api

My guess is you call from balabal to www.balabala/api or from www.balabala to balaba/api, set url to /api.

Comment: Hello and thanks for response but the url is right. When i enter in url it shows exactly what i expect.